# Convertendo (Mapear) uma Lista de uma entidade para outra referência de forma explítica

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Como faço para converter/mapear uma lista de uma entidade para outra referêcia de forma explícita. Veja um exemplo que consegui realizar com uma entidade:

```
public static explicit operator UserResponse(Entities.User entity)
{
        return new UserResponse()
        {
            Id = entity.Id,
            Role = entity.Role,
            Email = entity.Email,
            UserStatus = entity.UserStatus
        };
}
```

Assim, eu consigo converter de forma explicita dentro de uma regra de negócio:

```
(UserResponse) await _userRepository.Create((User) user);
```

Gostaria de fazer isso para uma lista, ao invés de usar o método abaixo:

```
public static List<UserResponse> FromIList<User>(IList<Entities.User> entity)
        {
            return entity.Select(item => new UserResponse()
            {
                Id = item.Id,
                Role = item.Role,
                Email = item.Email,
                UserStatus = item.UserStatus
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tendo as conversões explicitas, basta fazer o seguinte:

```
//Convertendo B para A
List<B> listB = listA.Select(a => (B)a).ToList();

//Convertendo A para B
List<A> listA = listB.Select(b => (A)b).ToList();
```

Com o exemplo acima estou supondo que você tenha as classes A e B:

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public static explicit operator A(B b)
    {
        return new A
        {
            Id = b.id_b,
            Role = b.prop_b1,
            Email = b.prop_b2
        };
    }
}

public class B
{
    public int id_b { get; set; }
    public string prop_b1 { get; set; }
    public string prop_b2 { get; set; }

    public static explicit operator B(A a)
    {
        return new B
        {
            id_b = a.Id,
            prop_b1 = a.Role,
            prop_b2 = a.Email
        };
    }
}
```

[Veja o exemplo no fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XlTmaK)

Comment: Usei o código criado por você no exemplo da minha resposta, espero que não seja problema.

Comment: @LINQ É uma honra pra mim! kkk :)

Answer (score 2):

Desde que as conversões sejam válidas, é possível usar o método de extensão [**`Cast`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=netframework-4.7.2) do LINQ.

Considerando o código [desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/359017/18246), ficaria assim.

```
var listB = listA.Cast<B>().ToList();
var listA = listB.Cast<A>().ToList();
```

Comment: Existe algo já pronto para entidades sem estarem numa que possuí essa facilidade de conversão?

Comment: Desculpa, não entendi. Sem estarem numa o quê?

Comment: Eu preciso fazer sempre a conversão explicíta para realizar, conforme o exemplo expressado na pergunta. Eu não precisei implementar com o Cast do Linq. Ao invés de implementar, já existe alguma lib que realiza essa tarefa automáticamente, ao invés de implementar?

Comment: Você quer saber se existe alguma biblioteca que implemente o operador de conversão explícito automaticamente? Tipo um AutoMapper só que implementando da forma mostrada na resposta do Wurthmann?

Comment: Show! eu cheguei a ver esse autmapper aqui... é bem bacana! Vou tentar utiliza-lo. Obrigado mais uma vez!